# Vue-Resource, can't get this.$http.post working in Vue instance

Tags: vue-resource, vuejs2

I am trying to post some data usng this.$http.post and I could not figure out how to pass in the data through the route api..

```
new Vue({

    el: '#root',

    data: {
        newName: '',
        nameList: []
    },

    methods: {
        addName(){
            this.nameList = this.nameList.concat(this.newName);
            var name = this.newName;
            this.newName = '';

            this.$http.post('/api/name', {name: name}).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.message);
            });
       }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.$http.get('/api/name').then((response) => {
            this.nameList= this.nameList.concat(JSON.parse(response.body));
            console.log(this.nameList);
        });
    }


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear, what is the exact issue, here, what exact API you are trying to hit.

If you are trying to hit: `/api/name/:someName`, you can do following

```
this.$http.post('/api/name/'+name ).then((response) => {
   console.log(response.message);
});
```

If you are trying to hit: `/api/:someName` with payload, you can do following

```
this.$http.post('/api/' + name, {name: name}).then((response) => {
   console.log(response.message);
});
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The first  answer helped. Thank you